# Move all SVG Elements to the upper left corner

Tags: javascript, svg

I got a SVG-Element and I want to fit it to the content by something similar to this way:

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var bb=svg.getBBox();
var bbx=bb.x;
var bby=bb.y;
var bbw=bb.width;
var bbh=bb.height;
var vb=[bbx,bby,bbw,bbh];
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", vb.join(" ") );
```

But now I first want to move all elements in the upper left corner (margin 10px). After that I want to make the svg-element fit to the conent in the way shown above.

How can I move all elements to the corner?

**JSfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/4pD9N/